# How was this differentiated?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How red-circled function with 1/D is equal to green-circled?
[image]

Note: `D` is equal to `dy/dx`.

Update: Complete pic
[image]

Comment: can you plot the whole function please?

Comment: What I think is , $\int \cos 2x= \frac {\sin 2x}2 $ ,but in this case , this was not integrated, because in that case, the previous term $\frac 18$ would also be changed to $\frac x8$.What was the actual question?

Comment: Please have a look, have updated question. @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: More context is needed. Please post the entire problem

Comment: The one writing this should be more careful. The $\frac{1}{D}$ probably stands for anti-differentiation, i.e. a primitive function of $\cos 2x$ is about to be calculated. An then later, the person writes $D$ also for a general constant. Also, this way of "solving" problems just putting formulas above each other without words are useless in my opinion.

Comment: The book was typeset incorrectly: for example, $e^{-x}$ is typeset as $e^x$ at least once, and $\cosh x$ is typeset as $\cos hx$. Maybe the $\sin 2x$ was meant to be $\cos(2x)$. What does it say in the box under "The G. Solution"; what is the part of the solution that was cropped out of the second photo?

Answer (score 0):

[Euler's notation](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Euler.27s_notation) for the first derivative is
$$ Df=D_xf=Df(x)=D_xf(x)$$
However in your text, you have
$$\frac{1}{D}\cos 2x$$
Which is ambiguous at best. To me it seems that the author poorly chose the letter $D$ as a function name. Perhaps somewhere in your text, the author wrote
$$f(x)=\ln\left|\sin 2x\right|+C$$
$$ D=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=2\cot 2x$$
And we have
$$\frac{1}{D}\cos 2x=\frac{\cos 2x}{2\cot 2x}=\frac{\sin 2x}{2}$$
As others have already stated, more context is needed.